# The mathematics of Schellings segregation model

Tags: algorithms, pr.probability

For those who don't know the model. You can read this [pdf](http://hsd.soc.cornell.edu/curricular/schelling_chapter_on_segregation.pdf). I want to find what is the probability that 2 nodes are each others neighbors when the algorithm converges (i.e. when all nodes are happy).

> Here's the model in a gist. You have a
>   grid (say 10x10). You have nodes of
>   two kind (red and green) 45 each. So
>   we have 10 empty spaces. We randomly
>   place the nodes on the grid. Now we
>   scan through this grid (Exact order
>   does not matter according to
>   Schelling). Each node wants a specific
>   percentage of people of same kind in
>   its [Moore neighborhood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_neighborhood) (say b = 50%
>   for each red and green). We calculate
>   the happiness of each node (a = Number
>   of neighbors of same kind/Number of
>   neighbors of different kind). If a
>   node is unhappy (a < b) it moves to an
>   empty cell where it knows it will be
>   happy. This movement can change the
>   dynamics of old as well as new
>   neighborhood. Algorithm converges when
>   all nodes are happy.

PS - I am looking for links for any mathematical analysis of the Schelling's model. I had posted this question on stackoverflow and was advised to post it here.